# Issue with "Document is loceked for editing" SharePoint library

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, document-library, document

I have problem with opening documents in SharePoint. For time to time users reported me that they can't open documents (word, excel but the most often excel), when they try to open they see "Document is locked for editing" or that "Documents is locked for other user" but none is editing documents. This is very annoying, because sometimes we must save copy of documents to be able to work.

How I can fix this?

I will very grateful for help,
Andrzej

Answer (score 0):

This is something that often happens when check in/out is not turned on. It can often be resolved by getting the last person to edit to reopen and close the document, However the permanent solution is to enable check in/out in your library settings.

Comment: What do you mind by saing "enable check in/out? I should for all time check out document before edit?

Comment: in the ribbon, **Library > Library Settings > Versioning Settings**
Then set require check out to yes. This will prompt for check out and ask to check back in when the document is closed in MS office.

Comment: But it will be problematic for us because We use Office Web Apps to be able to share documents... Does is any solution without check out/in?